# Как в sql запросе вычесть следующие id*n от другого id?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Столкнулся с тем, что не могу найти решения из коробки в MySQL, для поиска следующего id в таблице, когда

```
new id = max(id) - onPage*pageNum
```

```
onpage = 20; // постоянное значение
pageNum = $_GET['page']; // число, например, 2,3,4...100 и т.д.
```

Задача:
Сделать постраничную навигацию, без использования offset в sql запросе. Как я понял, есть популярное решение, когда мы работаем только с where id < id, который мы должны найти.

Дано:
Например таблица people, вида

```
create table persons (
id int not null auto_increment,
name varchar,
phone varchar,
primary key(id)
)
```

Что пробовал:

1. Делаю запрос, чтобы найти максимальный id.

```
select id 
from persons 
order by id desc 
limit 1
```

Сейчас я знаю максимальный id.

Например, этот id = 543.

Задача:
Как теперь найти ID, который равен 543 - 20 = 523 ?

Проблема:
Нужно вычесть реальные записи, то есть, какие-то id могут быть удалены из таблицы. Собственно, в этом и проблема. Я правильно понимаю, что в MySQL нельзя просто получить такой id?

Хотелось бы в итоге получить такой id и получить запрос вида:

```
select id 
from persons 
where id < 523
order by id desc 
limit 20
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Нет, id конечно получить нельзя из за разрывов в нумерации. данный подход эффективен  если у вас в навигации есть только кнопки "предыдущая" и "следующая". Можно конечно где то кешировать один раз найденные id, но тут возникает проблема что этот кеш придется чуть ли ни весь сбрасывать при любом изменении в БД.  Если выборки гораздо чаще, чем обновление данных в таблице это может быть конечно оправдано. А еще стоит посмотреть как часто люди выбирают страницу по номеру, обычно они все же пользуются "пред", "след" и можно работать по разному для номера страницы и для этих кнопок

Comment: А версия mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас не полные ID т.е. отсутствует записи в таблице, то нужно пронумеровать с начала используя оконные функции и уже имея непрерывный rowNumber работать с ним.

```
 select * from personsWithNumber
 where rowNumber between pageNumber*20 and (pageNumber+1)*20
```